# TikZ Picture matrix entry distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-calendar

I have a matrix (formed by `calendar`) in a tikz picture.
I have separated some days in the matrix by 3 rectangular blocks
but the edges are overlapping.
How can I prevent edges overlap? 
Thank you.
**bkarpuz**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
  \calendar (sep18) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \draw[draw=none,fill=orange,opacity=0.3] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) -- (sep18-2018-09-23.north east)
   -- (sep18-2018-09-30.south east) -- (sep18-2018-09-24.south west) -- cycle;
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-21.south east);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-24.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-24.south east);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-25.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-27.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First option, play with `day xshift` and `day yshift` until you faind the correct value to avoid overlapping:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
  \calendar (sep18) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered, day xshift=4ex, day yshift=3.15ex]; \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[orange,opacity=0.3] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-30.south east);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-21.south east);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-24.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-24.south east);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-25.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-27.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second option: draw rectangles based in middle coordinates between days and not on overlapping anchors.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar,backgrounds, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
  \calendar (sep18) [dates=2018-09-01 to 2018-09-last,week list,month label above centered]; \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[orange,opacity=0.3] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) rectangle (sep18-2018-09-30.south east);

 \coordinate (aux1) at ($(sep18-2018-09-21.south east)!.5!(sep18-2018-09-28.north east)$);
 \coordinate (aux2) at ($(sep18-2018-09-21.south east)!.5!(sep18-2018-09-29.north west)$);
 \draw[draw=black] (sep18-2018-09-17.north west) rectangle (aux1|-aux2);

 \draw[draw=black] ($(sep18-2018-09-17.south west)!.5!(sep18-2018-09-24.north west)$) rectangle ($(sep18-2018-09-24.south east)!.5!(sep18-2018-09-25.south west)$) coordinate (aux3);

 \draw[draw=black] (aux3) rectangle (aux1|-aux2);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]